# How to set Timeout for MultiPart Request in Dart?

Tags: http, flutter, dart

Here is my `MultiPartRequest` code

```
var request =
            http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(EMPLOYEE_PUNCH_IN_URL));

        request.fields['uid'] = userId;
        request.fields['location'] = location;
        request.fields['punchin_time'] = punchInTime;
        request.fields['punchin_location_name'] = address;

        var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            "photo", imageFile.path,
            contentType: MediaType("image", "$extension"));
        request.files.add(multiPartFile);
        http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

        var responseByteArray = await response.stream.toBytes();

        employeePunchInModel = standardSerializers.deserializeWith(
            EmployeePunchInModel.serializer,
            json.decode(utf8.decode(responseByteArray)));
        ......
```

I know how to set timeout to a normal http request. I have followed this link

[Set timeout for HTTPClient get() request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487818/set-timeout-for-httpclient-get-request)

I have tried adding timeout function in following ways but it won't work and my request gets completed

1.

```
 var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            "photo", imageFile.path,
            contentType: MediaType("image", "$extension")).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1));
```

2.

```
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1));
```

3.

```
var responseByteArray = await response.stream.toBytes().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 15));
```

But none of the above timeout works.

Comment: Option 1 sets a timeout on building the multipart request from the file. So if eg. it's a big file that takes a long time to read or device IO is slow, it will time out before the request is built.

Option 2 sets a timeout on receiving the response headers. This usually means that the server has received and processed the entire request and has responded with a status code.

Option 3 sets a timeout on receiving the rest of the response - the response body.

What do you actually want to set a timeout on??

Comment: @Ovidiu I want to set timeout for my http request which is going to the server

Comment: That's option 2 then. If the server doesn't receive, read and process the entire request, and then reply with an HTTP status code that gets back to the app, all within the given time, it will be considered a timeout.

Comment: Is this about C#?

Comment: @Momoro Its about Dart language and Flutter framework

Comment: Well, I found this: https://github.com/lejard-h/chopper/issues/49 (it's `dart`, but in `chopper`)

Answer (score 2):

Using [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http), this is my approach :

1. Create a Streamed Response that we're going to use for `onTimeOut` callback

```
StreamedResponse timeOutResponse({
  @required String httpMethod,
  @required dynamic error,
  @required String url,
}) { 
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'any': 'value',   
    'you': 'want for $error',
  };

  int statusCode = 404;  
  Uri destination = Uri.parse(url);
  String json = jsonEncode(body);
  
  return StreamedResponse(
    Stream.value(json.codeUnits),
    statusCode,
    request: Request(httpMethod, destination),
  );
}
```

2. Use the modified http multipart function from [Mahesh Jamdade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8253662/mahesh-jamdade) answer

```
Future<http.Response> makeAnyHttpRequest(String url,
  Map<String, dynamic> body,
  {Function onTimeout,
  Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 10)}) async {

     final request = http.MultipartRequest(
         'POST',
          Uri.parse('$url'),
       );
     
     final res = await request.send().timeout(
         duration,
         onTimeout: () {
           return timeOutResponse(
             httpMethod: 'MULTIPART POST',
             error: 'Request Time Out',
             url: url,
           );
         },
       );

     return await http.Response.fromStream(res);
  }
```

this way, instead of timeout exception, you can return the `onTimeOut` Http Response.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(EMPLOYEE_PUNCH_IN_URL));

  request.fields['uid'] = userId;
  request.fields['location'] = location;
  request.fields['punchin_time'] = punchInTime;
  request.fields['punchin_location_name'] = address;

  var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      "photo", imageFile.path,
      contentType: MediaType("image", "$extension"));
  request.files.add(multiPartFile);

  await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 1), onTimeout: () {
    throw "TimeOut";
  }).then((onValue) {
    var responseByteArray = await onValue.stream.toBytes();

    employeePunchInModel = standardSerializers.deserializeWith(
        EmployeePunchInModel.serializer,
        json.decode(utf8.decode(responseByteArray)));
  }).catchError((){ throw "TimeOut";});
```

Comment: Will give a try

Comment: I am getting an error https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pritishsawant-16.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202019-10-30%20at%208.40.31%20PM.png?alt=media&token=4ad9671c-fd59-4593-866b-6d70e591fc57

Comment: @Nudge ..I edited
      var responseByteArray = await onValue.stream.toBytes();

Comment: Does not work. I tried your solution. As you can see in the second step I mentioned in the question I was using the same solution you described. Maybe the timeout does not work for multipart http. I guess need to file a bug

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package with following code:

```
  try {
  final response = await Dio().post(requestFinal.item1, data:formData, options: option,
      onSendProgress: (sent, total) {
        print("uploadFile ${sent / total}");
      });

  print("Response Status code:: ${response.statusCode}");

  if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 299) {

    dynamic jsonResponse = response.data;
    print("response body :: $jsonResponse");
    final message = jsonResponse["msg"] ?? '';
    final status = jsonResponse["status"] ?? 400;
    final data = jsonResponse["data"];
    return HttpResponse(status: status, errMessage: message, json: data);
  }
  else {
    dynamic jsonResponse = response.data;
    print('*********************************************************');
    print("response body :: $jsonResponse");
    print('*********************************************************');
    var errMessage = jsonResponse["msg"];
    return HttpResponse(status: response.statusCode, errMessage: errMessage, json: jsonResponse);
  }
}
on DioError catch(error) {
  print('*********************************************************');
  print('Error Details :: ${error.message}');
  print('*********************************************************');
  dynamic jsonResponse = error.response.data;
  print('*********************************************************');
  print("response body :: $jsonResponse");
  print('*********************************************************');
  var errMessage = jsonResponse["message"] ?? "Something went wrong";
  return HttpResponse(status: jsonResponse["status"] , errMessage:  errMessage, json: null);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am aware of the Diorites library but I can't use it as it my office project and my team lead is not allowing it to use

Answer (score 0):

hey you can also use **dio 3.0.4**

A powerful Http client for Dart, which supports Interceptors, Global configuration, FormData, Request Cancellation, File downloading, Timeout etc.

Here is the link :[Http client for Dart](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which uses [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

declare your multipart function like this with your desired arguments

```
 Future<http.Response> makeAnyHttpRequest(String url,
      Map<String, dynamic> body,
      {Function onTimeout,
      Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 10)}) async {
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse('$url'),
    );
    final res = await request.send().timeout(duration, onTimeout: onTimeout);
    return await http.Response.fromStream(res);
  }
```

and then call it within a try catch block and you can catch the timeout exception by throwing the desired value on Timeout.

```
try{
    final res = makeAnyHttpRequest("<url>",{"body":"here"},onTimeout:(){
      throw 'TIME_OUT'; // Throw anything
    });
      
  }catch(_){
      if (_.toString() == 'TIME_OUT') { // catch the thrown value to detect TIMEOUT
        /// DO SOMETHING ON TIMEOUT    
          debugPrint('The request Timeout');   
     }
  }
}
```

The above approach would work for any http request as long as you have a `onTimeout` call back