# How can I display a Widget in a FutureBuilder when the server is down?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get an image that is on my server, but I am simulating an offline scenario. So I don't have access to the server, so I decided to use the `FutureBuilder` because otherwise I get an error similar to error 404 and my application dies.

I am getting this error:

```
SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 192.168.1.56, port = 59225)
```

Indeed in this image you can see that I do not have access to the server and I get error 111, but my application dies. I want to know how to control this behavior and for my application to continue, I want when I get a Widget to return.

[image]

this is my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

return FutureBuilder(
    future: http.get("http://192.168.1.56:3000/uploads/usuarios/523471653716.jpg"),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
      //never enters in offline mode
      print(snapshot.error);
```

NOTE: I do not know if it is the best way, I am simply trying to avoid the error that kills my app when it is not able to obtain an image, something like this:

```
FadeInImage(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        image: NetworkImage("http://192.168.1.56:3000/uploads/usuarios/523471653716.jpg"), //mode offline crash my app
        placeholder: AssetImage('assets/img/gallery.png'),
        fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

UPDATED my code:

```
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: http
 .get("http://192.168.1.56:3000/uploads/usuarios/523471653716.jpg"),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data.statusCode != 200) {
          return Text('Failed to load the image!');
        } else {
          return Image.memory(snapshot.data.bodyBytes);
        }
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Failed to make a request!');
      } else {
        return Text('Loading');
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Check the [FutureBuilder documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) you can use `snapshot.hasError` to check if something went wrong. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`AsyncSnapshot`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) provided as a second parameter to your [`builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder/builder.html) in [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) has two properties to check the result of the HTTP request: [`hasData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html) and [`hasError`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasError.html). If the request was successful, `hasData` will be true and you can get the actual data from [`data`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html) property. Otherwise, `hasError` will be set and the error is accessible at [`error`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/error.html) property. Also, when the request was successfully completed, but resulted in non-200 code, you should check [`data.statusCode`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseResponse/statusCode.html).

Thus, you need to check them in your builder and return the appropriate widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App')),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: http.get(
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Strombus_sinuatus_2010_G1.jpg"),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data.statusCode != 200) {
                  return Text('Failed to load the image!');
                } else {
                  return Image.memory(snapshot.data.bodyBytes);
                }
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Failed to make a request!');
              } else {
                return Text('Loading');
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try changing the URL of the image and see the results:

[image: demo]

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I put your same code and I get the same error. Maybe if you can exactly test my code with the link I put you can reproduce the error (obviously you will not be able to access said image)

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Approximately 2 minutes pass and I get this error.
 https://i.imgur.com/1Jxq7Dc.jpg

Comment: Try setting a timeout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51489701/750510

Comment: You won't believe me, but I have been trying something like this, but I am new to flutter, and I get syntax errors. i don't know how to combine this with my `FutureBuilder`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because of my little experience, but I've tried things like this 
 https://i.imgur.com/xWkKxx2.jpg , and I'm still getting the same problem.