# How Catch error : conection timed out, socketException in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, async-await, future

Hi I tried to catch a socketException when the server I am consulting is not available,  I tried with try{}catch{}, catchError and timeout, but it doesn't work

I need that if some time passes that the server does not respond, that it already stops waiting for it

The error is :

[image]

and I tried something like this

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487818/set-timeout-for-httpclient-get-request

Answer (score -2):

You are probably giving the code the wrong URL. Maybe this link will help You. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785581/socketexception-os-error-connection-refused-errno-111-in-flutter-using-djan). If You could just type in the URL and If You are using Python with flask or Django, or Node.js, that would help tremendously.

Update:

In the part where You say

```
final resp = await http.get(url).catchError({(onError) => print(onError)});
```

You should change it to this:

```
final resp = await http.get(url).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError); 
    return null;
});
```

Because You are catching the Error in the response and only printing it. You should `return null;` and escape that function.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I'm putting it right, but what I want is that when the server is off, I can catch that error to show some "connection error" message