# Proper way of setting request timeout for Flutter http requests?

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I need to set a timeout for http requests.

I have read [Set timeout for HTTPClient get() request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487818/set-timeout-for-httpclient-get-request) and it suggests us to use  `http.get(...).timeout(...)`.

However, I am worried: that `.timeout` is a method in `Future` class. Therefore, even if it timeouts, the http request is still ongoing! In other words, if the http request actually needs, say, 30 seconds to finish, and we use `timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))`, then even if it seems as if we have aborted the request, it is actually **still costing resources of the phone of the user for another 25 seconds**.

Therefore, I would appreciate it if there is a proper way to timeout requests. Or,  please correct me if I am wrong.

P.S. I know there is another thing, `HttpClient.connectionTimeout`. That is for connecting phase, not the time of whole request. Interestingly, when I go into the source code [see here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a4afb06b215eb9b40cb9cb17a6c69d03e413d8a0/sdk/lib/_http/http_impl.dart#L2446), I find that it also uses `some_future.timeout()` internally. Therefore, the resources, IMHO, are also not released when timeout.

Comment: Perhaps try calling [`HttpClientRequest.abort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/abort.html) from the `Future.timeout` callback?

Comment: @jamesdlin good suggestion! but how should I call it? I am using `IOClient`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the raw `HttpClient` API from `dart:io`, you can cancel an HTTP request by calling [`HttpClientRequest.abort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/abort.html) when your `Future` times out:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  var slowUrl = args.first;
  var httpClient = io.HttpClient();
  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(slowUrl));
  try {
    var response = await request
        .close()
        .then(
          (_) => print('Got eventual response'),
        )
        .timeout(
          const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
  } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
    print('Timed out');
    request.abort();
  }
}
```

When run with with an URL with a slow response, the above should print "Timed out" and not "Got eventual response".

However, `HttpClientRequest.abort` is (as of writing) a somewhat recent addition, and [currently it is not exposed in `package:http`](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/424).

Comment: Sounds great - thank you very much! However, I wonder how can I use it in IOClient - is the answer *no there is completely no way*? I think using my own httpclient seems not to be a good approach :/

Comment: Naively, I can do something like creating my own delegating HttpClient and HttpClientRequest, and then do such things inside it. But not sure whether it is a good practice.

Comment: AFAIK there's currently no way with `package:http`.

Comment: Tried it. It's the same result as using http package

Comment: @developer82 I don't understand what you mean.  As I already explained multiple times, this simply isn't possible (yet) with `package:http`.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (using only the http package):

```
var client = http.Client();

http.Request request = http.Request(method, Uri.parse(url));
request.body = body;
request.followRedirects = true;

var requestTask = client.send(request).timeout(Duration(seconds: 2));
var result = await requestTask
    .catchError((err) {
      print(err);
      client.close();
      return requestTask;
    })
    .whenComplete(() {
      client.close();
    });

var response = await http.Response.fromStream(result);
return response.body;
```