# Increase the idle time after connection is established in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, httpclient, flutter-http

1. If a connection is established, it will be closed after 15 seconds (if I am wrong please let me know the connection closing time), and the idle time cannot be extended. In my situation, multiple requests are made to the same domain and require a persistent connection, meaning the connection should be maintained even after 15 seconds. Is there another property that can be used to achieve this?
2. Prior to establishing a connection, if multiple requests are made, each request takes time to establish a connection. Is there a way to avoid this and reduce the time taken for all requests? For instance, in the screenshot below, 4 requests are made to the same domain before the connection is established, and each request takes around 2 seconds to establish a connection. Is there a way to decrease this time?

> Note: I tried using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and [http_client_helper](https://pub.dev/packages/http_client_helper) packages

[image]

3. But in some cases, when a request is raised within 15 seconds of the connection established, again the connection is re-establishing, please provide some suggestions on this. Below is my code snippet using http_client_helper.

   [image]

**Update 1**

Image 1

[image: Image 1]

Image 2

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Setting a timeout on the response which is a **Future** can help you do that. So you can have something like

```
final Response response = await HttpClientHelper(...).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
```

[This linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51489701/12325972) gives more details about handling timeout for connection and per requests. Let me know if it answers your question.

---

### Update

As Dharanidharan pointed out, the above suggestion lets you handle the time needed to establish a connection. To manage the idleTime after connection has been established, we need to use the [HttpClient class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html#:%7E:text=brightness_4-,HttpClient%20class,-abstract). This gives us access to low-level functionalities:

> Note: HttpClient provides low-level HTTP functionality. We recommend
> users start with more developer-friendly and composable APIs found in
> package:http.

As OP stated about the [idleTimeout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient/idleTimeout.html#:%7E:text=brightness_4-,idleTimeout%20property,-Duration%20idleTimeout) duration, `The default value is 15 seconds.` But using the idleTimeout property of the HttpClient class allows us the chance to modify this value.

```
  HttpClient client = HttpClient();

  Future<String> get(String url) async {
    String responseJson;

    try {
      client.idleTimeout = const Duration(minutes: 5);

      // first future
      // make a request to the url
      HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(baseUrl + url));

      // second future
      // close the request to get the response data
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

      // Process the response stream from the request
      final stringData = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

      // Manage the processed response
      responseJson = _response(stringData);
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('');
    } on ClientException {
      throw FetchDataException('');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        responseJson = e.toString();
      });
    }

    return responseJson;
  }
```

The above solution changes the idleTimeout from the default 15 seconds to 5 minutes. You may read more on [Making a simple GET request](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html#:%7E:text=Making%20a%20simple%20GET%20request%3A%20an%20example) to know the different ways to interact with the Helper class.

Here is a full code sample on [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0150ba1c91e82722b2347e055b6954b0) for anyone who wants a quick build test. (May not work directly in Dartpad because of import issues).

Comment: The timeout and connectionTimeOut are utilized to set the duration for establishing a connection. However, in my scenario, I need to set the duration after the connection is established. Specifically, I need to keep the already established connection alive for a specified time, such as 5 minutes, rather than the default 15 seconds. If I mean anything wrong point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Dharanidharan I understand. For that you may need to use the HttpClient Class which gives us access to low-level HTTP functionalities. I'll edit my answer to include more details.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and updated code snippets, I will try these.

Comment: Sure thing., much obliged. Do let us know how it works for you.

Comment: Your recommendation is effective in most cases, but it occasionally fails. I've set my idle time as 15 minutes in my code, but when I attempt to establish a connection at certain times, it takes longer than anticipated. Please review the screenshots below: the previous connection took 25ms, while the subsequent request took over 900ms. Do you have any suggestions for this issue? Kindly check on my query, I have updated the screenshots under Update 1 section